# Rolling mean, returning nan in dataframe pandas python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pandas, moving-average

So I have been trying to work out the moving average, and when outputed it gives me `NaN` for some reason

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import numpy as np
currentTime = datetime.now().date()

f = web.DataReader('goog', 'yahoo', start=2014-1-1, end=currentTime)
ma_50 = pd.rolling_mean(f, window=50)
print(ma_50)
```

The output just gives me date and the value that i want appears to be `NaN` like this:

```
2012-01-03         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN        NaN
```

Comment: works for me, also note your start date is *not* Jan-1 2014.

Comment: sorry, im confused what do you mean jan 1 2014, s

Comment: i use pycharm is that why

Comment: Just a side point, start=2014-1-1 looks suspiciously like a date, but is an integer `2014 - 1 - 1` and evaluates to `2012`, hence the date in your output. I doubt that pycharm is too blame. On second thought, I defer to @roadrunner66's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a rolling average of 50 days, so the first 49 days will have no data.Try a smaller number of averages to see it:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime
import numpy as np

currentTime = datetime.datetime.now().date()
df = web.DataReader('goog','yahoo', start='2016-5-1',end='2016-5-15')

ma_3 = pd.rolling_mean(df, window=3)

print(ma_3)
```

Output:

```
                  Open        High         Low       Close        Volume  \
Date                                                                       
2016-05-02         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN           NaN   
2016-05-03         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN           NaN   
2016-05-04  694.996663  699.410014  690.670003  695.423340  1.621233e+06   
2016-05-05  695.019999  699.970011  692.243327  696.496663  1.632333e+06   
2016-05-06  695.523336  704.643331  694.278992  702.750000  1.730700e+06   
2016-05-09  702.693339  710.963338  701.275655  708.483337  1.670633e+06   
2016-05-10  709.043335  718.023336  707.942322  715.733337  1.632533e+06   
2016-05-11  717.386658  722.230001  712.839986  717.123332  1.586100e+06   
2016-05-12  719.073324  722.409993  712.506653  717.259990  1.536867e+06   
2016-05-13  717.466655  720.130656  710.353333  713.143331  1.451600e+06   

             Adj Close  
Date                    
2016-05-02         NaN  
2016-05-03         NaN  
2016-05-04  695.423340  
2016-05-05  696.496663  
2016-05-06  702.750000  
2016-05-09  708.483337  
2016-05-10  715.733337  
2016-05-11  717.123332  
2016-05-12  717.259990  
2016-05-13  713.143331
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much, so if i was to do it with bigger mean how would i do it

Comment: You already did it but didn't notice it. Just scroll down to line 50 and your numbers will start appearing. You can't have a rolling average in the first 49 lines, since you don't know the past (in general). For this data set if you want it to start with the average in January, just get the data from 50 days back also.